Sanity GROQ Query to Fetch All Blog Posts 90 Days or Older
I have connected Sanity to a Next Js blog I am painstakingly coding myself. I am attempting to use a GROQ query search to retrieve blog posts older than 90 days. However, the code I have tried is not rendering anything on the screen. The following is my current code.
"use client"

import React from 'react'
import { client } from "../lib/sanity"
import { Post } from "../lib/interface"
import Link from "next/link";
import { PortableText } from '@portabletext/react';
import Image from "next/image";

async function getData() {
const query = `*[_type == 'post' && dateTime(_createdAt) >= dateTime(now()) - 60 * 60 * 24 * 90 |    order(_createdAt desc)]`;

const data = await client.fetch(query);

console.log(data)

return data;
}

export const revalidate = 60

export default async function movies() {
const data = (await getData()) as Post\[\];

return (

    <div className="xl:divide-y xl:divide-gray-200 xl:dark:divide-gray-700">
      <header className="pt-6 xl:pb-6">
        <div className="space-y-1 text-center">
          <div>
            <h1 className="text-3xl font-extrabold leading-9 tracking-tight text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-100 sm:text-4xl sm:leading-10 md:text-5xl md:leading-14">
              Movies
            </h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
    
      <div className="divide-y divide-gray-200 pb-7 dark:divide-gray-700 xl:divide-y-0">
        <div className="divide-y divide-gray-200 dark:divide-gray-700 xl:col-span-3 xl:row-span-2 xl:pb-0">
          <div className="prose max-w-none pb-8 pt-10 dark:prose-invert prose-lg">
            <ul>
              {data.map((post) => (
                <li key={post._id} className="py-4">
                  <article className="space-y-2 xl:grid xl:grid-cols-4 xl:items-baseline xl:space-y-0">
                    <div>
                      <p className="text-base font-medium leading-6 text-teal-500">
                        {new Date(post._createdAt).toISOString().split('T')[0]}
                      </p>
                    </div>
                      <Link 
                        href={`/post/${post.slug.current}`} 
                        prefetch 
                        className="space-y-3 xl:col-span-3"
                      >
                    <div>
                      <h3 className="text-2xl font-bold leading-8 tracking-tight text-gray 900 dark:text-gray-100">
                        {post.title}  
                      </h3>
                    </div>
    
                      <p className="prose max-w-none text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 line-clamp-2">
                        {post.overview}
                      </p>
                      </Link>
                  </article>
                </li>
              ) 
            )}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>  
    </div>

)
}

I have consulted Stack Overflow, GitHub, and GROQ cheat sheet I found in Google search, but can't seem to find any info on this specific scenario. Any way that I can achieve this?

remove "use client" from then top and try again, because a client side component cannot be async.

I tried that but it did not work. Still coming up with empty array when I console log 'data'
